# Call another function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui

I am sure this is ridiculously easy. I want to call another function from jQuery, or include it inline. Example:

```
$( "#drag-box-facebook" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" }, function() {alert("")});
```

However this doesn't work, and I can't work out why.

**Update** To clarify, the basic function of dragging works fine, it is just that the next function isn't called.

The most basic version is obviously

```
$( "#drag-box-facebook" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsA2P/)

Comment: What is the intent of this?

Comment: The actual usage will be to save a simple variable in to local storage

Comment: When is the function supposed to get executed?

Comment: @crush Once the element has been dropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call functions pretty easily... on start, drag, or stop.
You just need to define when it runs.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  start: function() {
    alert("start");
  },
  drag: function() {
     alert("drag");
  },
  stop: function() {
     alert("stop");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the jQuery UI documentation, you would have to place an event in front of the function, so that it will know when to trigger the function.

For example, if you wanted the function to be triggered when the draggable is created, you'd use:

```
$( "#drag-box-facebook" ).draggable({
   revert: "invalid", 
   create: function() { alert(""); }
});
```

Other events available are: create, drag, start and stop. The full documentation is on the [jQuery UI page](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable).

If you want it to happen when the dragging is done, you would use `stop`.